# how to view nested page table entries in qemu?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, qemu, hypervisor

In qemu, If I have my OS (or Hypervisor) virtualizing a guest OS, is there any command to print the nested page table entries as we do for native page entries by the "info pg" command?

Or is there any way to deduce the nested page table entries from the host page table?

Comment: QEMU uses KVM to virtualize the guest CPU's. You can print nested page table entries in __direct_map functions in KVM module.

Comment: I don't use KVM in my setup. I use qemu just to emulate an amd phenom processor in order to test my system which consist of a hypervisor hosting a linux guest. Now I am interested in viewing the evolution of nested page table entries created by my hypervisor.

Comment: Nested page table can be setup only in supervisor mode. Nested page table emulation doesn't make sense to me but perhaps you can confirm it through qemu mailing list/irc.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I 've read about it ([the turtle project](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Ben-Yehuda.pdf)) for a while now so i thought they would have implemented it. Anyway, Do you think there is a way to have access to this table (EPT) if I were running my system on a real npt featured hardware?

Comment: I don't know if any such API already exists (the only way I know requires changing the hypervisor). The turtle project uses Shadow Page Tables in the host and Nested Page Tables inside the guest hypervisor.